# Arduino restarts problem

Tags: arduino-mega

I want to assign `-1` to `count` variable again when `count == 16` but when I have assigned `-1` inside the `if` condition I have marked below in the code, the Arduino restarts.

Can anyone guess what is wrong here?

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <hid.h>
#include <hiduniversal.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <Usb.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <hidboot.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define DISPLAY_WIDTH 16

// initialize the LCD library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

USB     Usb;
USBHub     Hub(&Usb);
HIDUniversal Hid(&Usb);
HIDBoot<HID_PROTOCOL_KEYBOARD>    Keyboard(&Usb);

int count = -1;
char drawNo[4];
int m = 0;
int turn;
class KbdRptParser : public KeyboardReportParser {
    void PrintKey(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
protected:
    virtual void OnKeyDown(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key);
    virtual void OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key);
};

void KbdRptParser::OnKeyDown(uint8_t mod, uint8_t key) {
    uint8_t c = OemToAscii(mod, key);
    count++;

    if (c)
    { OnKeyPressed(c); }
}

/* what to do when symbol arrives */
void KbdRptParser::OnKeyPressed(uint8_t key) {
    static uint32_t next_time = 0;      //watchdog
    static uint8_t current_cursor = 0;  //tracks current cursor position

    if (millis() > next_time) {
        lcd.clear();
        current_cursor = 0;
        delay(5);    //LCD-specific
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    }//if( millis() > next_time ...

    next_time = millis() + 200;  //reset watchdog

    if (current_cursor++ == (DISPLAY_WIDTH + 1)) {    //switch to second line if cursor outside the screen
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    }

    int keys = (int) key;

    if (count == 4 | count == 5 | count == 6 | count == 7) {
        turn++;
        drawNo[m] = (char)keys;
        //lcd.print(drawNo[m]);
        Serial.print(drawNo[m]);
        Serial.print(m);
        ++m;
    }

    if (count == 16) {
        Serial.println("Counter equals 16 NOW");
        printScreen();
        delay(200);
        count = -1; /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Here is the problem*/

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(drawNo);  i++) {
            drawNo[i] = (char)0;
        }
    }
}
void printScreen() {
    int j;
    lcd.print(" DRAW NO : ");

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        lcd.print(drawNo[j]);
    }
}
KbdRptParser Prs;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("Start");

    if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
        Serial.println("OSC did not start.");
    }

    delay(200);
    Hid.SetReportParser(0, (HIDReportParser *)&Prs);
    // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
    lcd.begin(DISPLAY_WIDTH, 2);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.noAutoscroll();
    lcd.print("Scan Your Code");
    delay(200);
}

void loop() {
    Usb.Task();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int m = 0;
...
    drawNo[m] = (char)keys;
...
    ++m;
```

No other references to *m* in your code. Therefore *m* keeps increasing and you are writing outside the bounds of the array *drawNo*, corrupting memory.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is the count. Did you try moving it to above the serial print so that you can be sure of the report?

```
if (count == 16) {
        count = -1; /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Here is the problem*/       
        Serial.println("Counter equals 16 NOW");
        printScreen();
        delay(200);


        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(drawNo);  i++) {
            drawNo[i] = (char)0;
        }
```

Comment: No problem still exists.. any other idea?

Comment: Before you must see "Counter equals 16 NOW" now with the changed code do you see "Counter equals 16 NOW"?

Comment: @ Visual Micro Ya it prints "Counter equals 16 NOW" on serial Monitor,and also I have printed the value of count and it also proved that count is -1 now. ! but why is that board restart??

Comment: What Nick has said is right. It's because ++m is never reset

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. problem solved.